# Error when installing hardware accelerated execution manager - VT-x is not turned on

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I try to run android and I get this error :

> CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

So I try to install the **hardware accelerated** from this folder *C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager* 
I get this error :

[image]

Virtualisation is enabled in my OS (I use **Intel® Processor Identification Utility** to check if it is enabled) 
[image]

It's the first time I try to run an android application I can't understand this error can someone help me please?

Comment: is it enabled in the bios?

Comment: @Lino I don't know how to verify if it is enabled in the bios I check but I don't found virtualisation that's why I use Intel® Processor Identification Utility